# How to push and consume a message from Spring boot to standalone JBoss Wildfly 10 Artemis Activemq?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss-eap-7, activemq-artemis

I have written a Spring Boot application which aims to push and consume a message from JBoss Wildfly 10 ActiveMQ Artemis (NOTE: not Apache ActiveMQ 5.x). I am running this code through Spring Tool Suite.

I have also setup JBoss Wildfly 10 on my local system (on 8080 port) and have run the same in `standalone-full.xml` profile in order to create a queue called `TestQ` in the messaging subsystems of Wildfly.

Next I used `JMSTemplate` in the Spring Boot code for pushing and consuming the message in the above mentioned queue with the following things in `application.properties`:

```
spring.activemq.username=admin
spring.activemq.username=admin
spring.activemq.broker-url=http://localhost:8080
```

However, I am getting `Could not send message` error while running my code.

Can you please suggest what changes would be required?

My basic aim is to push and consume message from this external queue using Spring Boot.

I have tried alternatives on the net, but every example I get is for Apache ActiveMQ and not ActiveMQ Artemis embedded into JBoss Wildfly which is required.

I have the below 2 classes:

1.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class App  {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Launch the application
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);

        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

        System.out.println("Sending a JMS message.");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("sampleQueue", "Hello world!");
    } 
}
```

2.

```java
@Component
public class ReceiveMessage {

    @JmsListener(destination = "sampleQueue")
    public void receiveMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Received :" + msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Set `org.apache.activemq.artemis` logging to DEBUG (on both client and server, if different hosts/different WildFly applications), recycle the app servers, and re-run some end-to-end tests.  This is probably the fastest/most effective way to determine 1) who's failing, and 2) what exactly is the failure

Comment: I have mentioned the activemq broker url above. Does that seem ok for standalone wildfly?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the properties in `application.properties` are for an ActiveMQ 5.x client rather than an ActiveMQ Artemis client. As the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-messaging.html#boot-features-artemis) says:

> Artemis configuration is controlled by external configuration properties in `spring.artemis.*`.

Also, you should to expose a port on Wildfly directly to the ActiveMQ Artemis broker rather than using the consolidated port `8080` as this requires `httpUpgradeEnabled` to be set to `true` on the Artemis client's URL and there is no way to do that using the Spring Boot integration for some reason.

Comment: That's a good guess... but I *hate* "guesses".  +1, and I encourage the OP to try it (and "accept" your answer if it works).  Q: What would you suggest if it doesn't work?  My vote is "verbose logging".  Do you have an alternate suggestion?  Q: What's a good "Hello world" to verify you've got a good  ActiveMQ Artemis install and config?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried changing the properties as below, in this case I did not get any error message but message was also not pushed to the queue:
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=127.0.0.1
spring.artemis.port=8080
spring.artemis.user=jboss
spring.artemis.password=jboss@123

Any thing else I could include? Or instead of JMSTemplate any other method I could use?

Comment: I updated my comment to address your question, Ralph. In short, I think your problem is using `8080`. You need to connect directly to Artemis.

Comment: Yes I tried to change the port in properties to 61616 but still it's not working. Do you have any simple code basic spring boot code that pushes message to jboss wildfly queue so that I could use that as reference?

Comment: Did you modify the Wildfly configuration to expose port `61616`? This port is not exposed by default. There is a Sping Boot example shipped with the Artemis broker which you can [see online](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/standard/spring-boot-integration), but it doesn't use Wildfly and it uses an AMQP client rather than the Artemis core client.

Comment: @RalphRockmore can you post the answer on your question if you resolved your problem? i ran into the same problem and did not know how to fix it

Comment: @JustinBertram, thank you for the `httpUpgradeEnabled` tip.

The following provided as a Broker URL worked for me: `tcp://localhost:8080?httpUpgradeEnabled=true`. I used the standard `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`  from `artemis-jms-client:2.20.0`.